# How can I follow Flutter UI Android Studio test execution on device?

Tags: android-studio, user-interface, flutter, automated-tests, flutter-test

I wrote a Flutter Widget plugin with user interface automated testing using Android Studio based on [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag).

Tests execute properly but are quite abstract to write without following what happens on the device UI. All I see is that the test executes properly and the duration. The device is plugged  and works properly but shows nothing related to the tests.

Is there a way to execute the UI tests from Android Studio and follow the execution on the device UI to simplify the writing of UI tests?

I would like to avoid using a solution based on [screenshots](https://github.com/mmcc007/screenshots) as it would not be convenient to have to continuously open an image to follow what is happening.

Comment: flutter docs ( faq ) on whats in the SDK mention "headless" test runner.  Usually , headless means no UI. So nothing for u to screenshot.  see the docs

Comment: Hi @RobertRowntree, thanks for your reply.Yes, I can see that some [documents mention headless testing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Flutter's-modes). However, I didn't read that all UI Flutter tests are necessarily headless. Also, it seems possible to [take screenshots from UI tests](https://github.com/mmcc007/screenshots#modifying-tests-for-screenshots) (which is not what I am looking for). Therefore, I suspect that it may be possible to follow the test execution on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing), there are 3 types of tests:

- Unit
- Widget
- Integration

Integration testing is the one that allows following the test execution on a device or a simulator.

Comment: Also, Flutter integration testing is simpler on Android using the Flutster plugin as a Flutter tester: https://pub.dev/packages/flutster